# How to set a new list in a WPF ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am implementing a simple MVVM WPF application with simple databrowsing commands.

There is a xaml-window with a listbox

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxPersons" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,10,10,5" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Besides there is a textbox to insert the where-clause

```
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Margin="0,5,10,5" Name="textBoxWhereClause" />
```

Persons is a ObservableCollection. I implemented simple Add / Delete / Change Commands for the persons. This works.

Question: what do i have to do, if the user performs a new query resulting in a completely new collection? How can a bind the new collection dynamically to the listbox?

I am a WPF beginner and helpless.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: You could clear your Persons Collection and fill the now empty collection with the new results.

Comment: yes thanks, thats true, but there are about 50,000 persons in the table. This could result in performance difficulties.

Comment: As Haris Hassan answered you could easily just change the bound collection to the newly loaded one. And maybe to address your performance you could load the new collection in the background by a different task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`How can I bind the new collection dynamically to the listbox?`

You don't need to reset the binding. Binding is already there you only need to update the binding source.

Simply you have to replace the `Persons` collection with newly retrieved results

You must have something similar to this in your View Model

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> _Person ;
public ObservableCollection<Person> Person
{
    get
    {  
        return _Person;
    }
    set
    {
        _Person = value;
        OnPrpertyChanged("Person");
    }
}
```

you can do `Person = YourNewCollection;` //newly retrieved results

`but there are about 50,000 persons in the table. This could result in performance difficulties`

There are two things you can do

1) only retrieve limited number of records at a time and provide user next back buttons. Kind of paging.

2) use `virtualization` option in ListBox so that UI can be responsive and efficient. It makes sure only those objects are loaded from Person collection into listbox which are can be displayed at a certain point of time